# EEPROM in beaglebone black

Tags: i2c, eeprom, beaglebone-black

I want to disable EEPROM in beaglebone black by unloading i2c-omap driver. Will it create problem in hardware or any other software support? What should I expect ?

Comment: Your question really is: What devices are attached on the I2C busses. Do you have the circuit diagram of BBB and board documentation?

Comment: Are there any resistors you could lift off to disconnect the EEPROM from I2C? If this disabling is a security matter, a physical barrier is probably more secure than a missing driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BeagleBone Black System Reference Manual](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1685587.pdf)

> 5.3.2: A single 32KB EEPROM is provided on I2C0 th
>   at holds the board information. This
>   information includes board name, serial number, and revision information

If you search for I²C in that document:

- 6.9.1: HDMI Framer The TDA19988 is a High-Definition Multimedia Interface (HDMI) 1.4a transmitter.
- 6.1.1: TPS65217C PMIC The main Power Management IC (PMIC) in the system
- 8.1: EEPROM Each cape must have its own EEPROM containing information that will allow the SW to identify the board and to configure the expansion headers pins as needed.

Whether or not you'll be running into problems is a matter if are you using any of these devices or a I²C device you wired up yourself.

Comment: IIRC, the TPS65217C is crucial to the device working... without it the device won't turn on (all power to the processor is routed through it).

Comment: @helloworld922 I really don't know. The system should be able to bootstrap without writing / reading to the device, otherwise it would never power up. I didn't read the entire chapter.

Comment: hmm... true, it would be kind of hard to power on if communication from the device you're suppose to power is required.